# Get user location when gps is now allowed

Tags: javascript, titanium, appcelerator

If the user denies gps permission asked in the start of app then is there any way we can determine its location or at least country and city somehow.?? via network or somehow from ip .?

Comment: if you do try this and it works, there is a possibility that apple will reject your application. If the user doesnt want to be tracked, then you should not track them

Answer (score 1):

You can try to detect country using one of the GeoIP libraries, eg. http://www.maxmind.com/en/javascript

Some of this services provides also cities. It's not always accurate but in most cases should be correct.